# PC stutter / freeze when downloading at over 200mpbs, safe mode works fine @ 700mpbs+

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, freeze, download

I have been looking for a solution on both the internet, official support sites and whatnot and can't find a solution for my problem. Maybe someone here can help me troubleshoot further.

So, the problem: I have a 1000mbps internet connection. When I boot up in Safe Mode with networking (windows 10) or if I uninstall my video adapter driver in normal mode, i can perform the speedtests just fine. Usually in the range of 600-900mpbs results. But under normal conditions (with nvidia latest drivers - or any nvidia driver version for that matter, tried many more) my computer starts freezing whenever i reach 200mbps mark and kinda fluctuates there. Cannot move the mouse, no input from keyboard, basically 3 seconds worth of freeze, following a 1 sec normal GUI flow, then again freeze, untill the download or speed test is over. I can play games with max settings no problem. Only when downloading at 10MB/s+ my PC seems it can't handle it. Uninstalling the video card driver solves the problem. But.. i need a video driver!

**My hardware - extensions over the base system:**

Nvidia GeForce 980 ti G1 gaming

2 x Samsung EVO 850 SSD with Windows 10 pro.

**My hardware - base system (PSU, mobo, ram, cpu still the same):**

http://www.pcgarage.ro/sisteme-pc-garage/pc-garage/master/

Now, the stuff I came up with:

1. It might be the power supply? Can't handle the load? I've read it's a solid one and should be more than enough for my machine..
2. Can the video card be faulty? How to check? Why only when downloading at high speeds my whole PC is put to a crawl? Simptoms do not repeat using a 760gtx and Win7...

How can I check what's wrong without risking burning any hardware components? Or ask for warranty on the graphics card if needed? Or change my PSU and make sure the problems go away?!

Edit: win10 is fresh install! worked perfectly untill nvidia drivers auto-updated.

Edit #2: did FuMark stress test, up to 100% power consumption of card, nothing happened - score 5065 on 1080p preset. Also did CPU Burner, again, nothing unusual happened.

Edit #3: when i start the speedtest, the GPU core clock and memory clock go to 100%! causing my pc to slowdown. Stresstests with 100% gpu and memory and cpu do NOT cause my pc to freeze. Problem occurs only when downloading! what in the name of nvidia is happening?! The freeze corresponds with the 100% graph blocks in the screenshot below. Again, if I uninstall the drivers, or do anything else besides downloading at high speeds, everything is normal :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jde9.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you it probably isn't the power supply. i have a similar setup, ram and cpu performance are nowhere near close to max or even 30 % usage.  i havent monitored the GPU yet but at speeds over 600mbps my computer jutters for a few seconds, mouse locks up as well. it gets worse the closer to 800-1000 i get.  also have windows 10.

im going to be testing tonight, i'll let you know if i come up with anything

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)